# How to return a float in OCaml?

Tags: list, function, integer, ocaml

I have written this simple function in OCaml to calculate the sum of a List:

```
let rec sum lst = 
     match lst with
     | [] -> 0.0
     | h :: t -> h + sum t
```

However I receive an Error when I call it:

```
Error: This expression has type float
   but an expression was expected of type int
```

How can I rewrite this function so it is able to sum a List of floats and return a zero as a float (0.0) if the List is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OCaml integer math is done with `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`. Floating point math is done with `+.`, `-.`, `*.`, and `/.`

You want:

```
let rec sum lst = 
  match lst with
  | [] -> 0.0
  | h :: t -> h +. sum t
```

Although you *could* just write the following. The trailing `0` on floating point literals is not required. This has the benefit of being tail-recursive.

```
let sum = List.fold_left (+.) 0.
```